# Why can't low rep users post comments until they have 50 rep?

Tags: discussion, support

I am trying to post a comment on a question asked by a user to get clarity, but because (ATM) I have only 8 rep, I am unable to as it says I need 50.

What is the purpose of this? I want to be able to help the OP of the question.

Comment: The purpose of this is to stop low rep users from spamming comments. Answers from low rep users are also afforded additional scrutiny.

Comment: Because they do so many unconstructive things that take a lot of work to clean up.  Like not researching their question, this one has been asked multiple times before.  Sigh.

Comment: Preventing spam is one reason, as comments are not specifically reviewed and may not be seen by someone who can delete spam (there are way too many of them) but answers and questions by new users are. Another reason is that if the reputation requirement was lowered, we'd be overrun by comments such as "can you help me please, I have a slightly different problem.." or "thanks, this answer helped me sooo much.!!", which no one really wants. For example, on YouTube, 80% of comments are useless and utterly garbage, and SO doesn't want that, hence the requirement of having positively contributed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legitimate tool for "helping the OP" is to answer the question. Which you can do even with 1 rep.

Comments should not be used to answer a question. They should be used to get additional information about the question or somesuch. If you cannot answer the question without commenting first (to get added information), just move on to another question.

Comment: As I said, I wanted to ask for clarity, not to answer the question then and there. It seems unfair to those with a genuine want to aid to be punished and forced to add an answer in order tyo make a comment...

Comment: @swiftie821: I said nothing about adding an answer to make a comment. I said *move on*. If you don't have enough rep to comment, then move on to another question. This is Stack Overflow; we have hundreds of thousands of people here. Odds are good someone else will post the comment you wanted to.

Comment: @swiftie821: you should *definitely* ***not*** post an answer [because I cannot comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34900649/2564301). Depending on its contents, you may attract downvotes and it may get flagged for not being an answer. BTW this indeed is meant as punishment – not for you, but for the ones that abused the system before. It's like "why do I have to stop for a red light, even when I watch out for traffic?" – because others do not.